# Uncaught TypeError: postList.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
const [postList, setPostList] = useState([])

const q = query(collection(db, "examples"), where("title", "==", title))
try {
  const posts = await getDocs(q)
  posts.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.data())
  })
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message)
}
```

I tried to check the docs list i got from query with console. log , the list is fine and it's what I  expected.
The problem got me is, i am not sure if i did it right, when i tried to set the document lists i query to the state object. Below is what i did

```
const q = query(collection(db, "examples"), where("title", "==", title))
try {
  const posts = await getDocs(q)
  posts.forEach((doc) => {
    setPostList(...postList, doc.data())
  })
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message)
}
```

I subsequently tried to map data I want into components. It said

> "Uncaught TypeError: postList.map is not a function".

Please kindly advise how I could put `doc.data()` into iterable. Thanks.

```
const getData = async () => {

    const q = query(collection(db, "data"), where("title", "==", title))
    try {
        const posts = await getDocs(q)
        const data = posts.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }))
        setPostList(data)
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message)
    }

}
```

.........
.....

```
        postList.map((doc) => {
            <Block question={doc.data().item} answer={doc.data().details} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`postList` must be an array in this case so you use `map()`. But `setPostList(...postList, doc.data())` will be an object. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
const posts = await getDocs(q)
const data = posts.docs.map((d) => ({ id: d.id, ...d.data() }))

setPostList(data)
```

Comment: i tried this before and the console alert "doc.data is not a function"

Comment: @user145472 can you share your code that tried?

Comment: please check the code above

Comment: @user145472 can you please rename the doc in nap to just d. As in my updated answer? It seems to be conflicting with doc function of firestore

Comment: i tried, console log: "TypeError: d.data is not a function"

Comment: @user145472 in your ui it should be `postLists.map(post => .....` and thrn question={post.item}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248033/discussion-between-user145472-and-dharmaraj).